# How to get/set application name in .dxf for Groupcode 1001?

Tags: java, converters, dxf, application-name

I convert geodata (coordinates, attributes,...) to a dxf file.

I write attributes into extended data, but under the group code `1001` there must be an application name. I tried to write `"Test"` and some other words in it, but nothing works.

I receive the error message:

> Invalid application name in 1001 group on line 50.

What is the application name in this context, where can I get it or whatever?

[image: Example picture with part from my dxf.]

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that DXF group `1001` should contain the Application ID of the Extended Entity Data (xData) attached to your entity.

This application ID may be an arbitrary name which fulfils the requiremnts of a symbol table name (which are documented as part of the AutoLISP [snvalid](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-2EFBE198-9860-456B-A090-206C743ACB90) function). When specifying an Application ID, you should try to ensure that it is unique and you should **AVOID** using `ACAD`, as this is reserved and used internally by AutoCAD.

The key point that is causing your file to fail to be parsed is that every Application ID referenced by xData within the file must also appear as a symbol table name within the [`APPID` symbol table](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-6E3140E9-E560-4C77-904E-480382F0553E).